# Drupal 7 AJAX and "CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected." in captcha-7.x-1.x-dev

Tags: ajax, drupal, captcha

I am experiencing problems with the `captcha-7.x-1.x-dev` version , In a form if i used any AJAX processed fields, after I submit it I receive the error `CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected.`. If there are no AJAX processed fields means it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in the current 7.x-1.0-beta2 version of the Captcha module. However, [jay.daysand](https://drupal.org/user/799552) put in a [comment on a issue](https://drupal.org/node/918856#comment-7302582) saying he created a module to fix this issue that you can download and use:

> Check out the experimental fix module
>   http://drupal.org/sandbox/dansandj/1970786 and let me know if it
>   solves your problems. I can easily add support for more endpoints than
>   just "file/ajax", just let me know.

I downloaded this module and it works great, but had to modify the `captcha_ajax_fix_captcha_element_value()` method to check for FAPI ajax calls:

```
  // If this is form is an AJAX submission to "file/ajax", don't process the
  // CAPTCHA element.
  if (arg(0) == 'file' && arg(1) == 'ajax' || arg(0) == 'system' && arg(1) == 'ajax') {
    $element['#processed'] = TRUE;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and i was searching for a patch and i found it.
this might be useful
 https://www.drupal.org/node/1395184

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27936/captcha-session-reuse-attack-detected-error-message-when-form-is-submitted